# Disable Translate Button For particular Schema

Tags: web8, translation-manager

I am working with SDL Web 8.1, I need to disable the Translate button for any particular Schema.

I tried removing the Translate property of all the fields with a translate option but it didn't work.

Can anybody suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: Please can you check the version of Tridion you have? Is it Web 8.1? Are you trying to do this for only one schema? I wasn't sure from your question.

Comment: Hi Cronin,

Yes its WEB 8.1, yes you are right I am trying it for one schema. Awaiting for your suggestion.

Comment: It is not available out of the box as far as I remember. A UI extension could do it, but be careful with performance impact. The translate enable state is loaded async, but still - you can end up getting a lot of items to see which schema they use.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi Santosh,
Already Implemented the logic for disable translation button for select schema. please find below js and configuration code.**

**Editior.Config:**

```
 <ext:commandextensions>
          <ext:commands>           
            <ext:command name="Translate" extendingcommand="SecureTranslate" />         
          </ext:commands>         
 </ext:commandextensions>
```

**Secure.JS:**

```
Tridion.CommandExtensions.SecureTranslate = function (name) {
    Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "Tridion.CommandExtensions.SecureTranslate");
    this.addInterface("Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.Base.Commands.CommandBase", [name || "SecureTranslate"]);
};


Tridion.CommandExtensions.SecureTranslate.prototype._isAvailable = function (selection, pipeline) {

    var itemTitle = "";
    var items = selection.getItems();
    if (items.length != 1) {
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var itemId = selection.getItem(i);
        var item = $models.getItem(itemId);

        if (item.isLoaded() == false) {
            item.load();
        }
        if (item.isLoaded(true) && Tridion.Type.isFunction(item.getMetadataSchemaId)) {
            var schemaId = item.getMetadataSchemaId();
            var itemInfo = $models.getItem(schemaId);
            if (itemInfo != null) {
            itemTitle = itemInfo.getStaticTitle();
             }
        }
        // Check here the schema Title and Disabled the Translate
        if (item) {
            if (item.getItemType() == $const.ItemType.VIRTUAL_FOLDER) {
                if (itemTitle !== "Test Schema") {
                    if (pipeline) {
                        pipeline.stop = true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
};

/*
*Checks whether to enable / disable the extension 
*/
Tridion.CommandExtensions.SecureTranslate.prototype._isEnabled = function (selection, pipeline) {
    if (pipeline) {
        pipeline.stop = true;
    }
    return this._isAvailable(selection, pipeline);
};
/*
* default implementation
*/
Tridion.CommandExtensions.SecureTranslate.prototype._execute = function (selection, pipeline) {
    if (pipeline) {
        pipeline.stop = false;
    }
}
```